# How to use dynamic golang html template id with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, go, go-templates

Hi I have a html image button with dynamic id inside range in golang template. I need to add a javascript function to it. But the problem is that how could I use this dynamic Id in javascript?

My HTML

```
{{range $i, $e := .Process}}
   <input id="id{{.}}" type="image" src="/images/icons/pencil.png" alt="edit" width="15" height="15">
{{end}}
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $().ready(function() {
            $('#id{{.}}').click(function() {
                $('#hidebody').toggle();

            });
        });
    </script>
```

How to solve this? Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give those buttons a class.

```
{{range $i, $e := .Process}}
   <input id="{{.}}" class="img-buttons" type="image" src="/images/icons/pencil.png" alt="edit" width="15" height="15">
{{end}}
```

In javascript you can do,

```
$(".img-buttons").click ( function() {
    $(this).attr( "id" ); // get Id
});
```

Instead of the id you can use html [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) if that suits you better.

HTML:

```
{{range $i, $e := .Process}}
   <input data-id="{{.}}" class="img-buttons" type="image" src="/images/icons/pencil.png" alt="edit" width="15" height="15">
{{end}}
```

JS:

```
$(".img-buttons").click ( function() {
    $(this).data( "id" ); // get Id
});
```